# Algorithm - Game item drop probability

Tags: probability, combinations, random-walk, algorithmic-game-theory

My math knowledge is very limited but I came across a problem that requires some serious understanding of probabilities.

That being said, I have a game which has a box and allows customizing the drop chances of items inside that box on the following manner:

**B***min* = Minimum items in Box

**B***max* = Maximum items in Box

**B***items* = [ **I***1* ... **I***n*]

**B***chances* = [ **C***1* ... **C***n*]

Note: ∑ **B***chances* has to equal 100

The game will then RNG a **B*set*** between **B***min* and **B***max*, and after that will start cycling through **B***items*, by order, performing an % RNG on that item's **C** to decide if its picked. The cycle will keep looping until **B*set*** items have been picked. **But once an item has been picked it can't be picked again (no repetitions).**

This is all fine and dandy, but what I wish to accomplish is an algorithm that given any **B***min*, **B***max* and **B***chances* will allow me to calculate P(**I***x*) (Probability that item *x* will be inside the box).

The idea is to generate a **P***items* = [P(**I***1*) ... P(**I***n*)]

As I previously mentioned, my math background is very poor and when I tried to accomplish this through simple Combinations and basic Probabilities all I came up with was an algorithm with exponential complexity as **B***max* and/or ***n*** increased (too embarrassed to even mention).

My question is if there is any way of accomplishing this through math, either accurately or within small margin of error, without exponential complexity.

Thank you

*RNG: Random Number Generator

Edit: Since it seems I wasn't able to clarify the problem properly, maybe this will serve as a 1000 words:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: What does RNG mean?

Comment: Is it 'random number generator'?

Comment: Sorry for not being explicit. RNG is indeed Random Number Generator. For **Bset** a random number is generated between **B**min and **B**max inclusive. And for the **C** a random number is generated between 0 and 100 and if the generated number is below **C** the item is picked.

Comment: This seems like a complicated procedure.  Are the chances for the various items different?  Is there a problem that you are trying to solve by this method?  If so, can you state the problem, please?  There may be a simpler solution method.

Comment: The game itself can't be modified and really only accepts a Bmin between 1 and 8 and and a Bmax between Bmin and 8. It also only accepts an array/list of numerical weights (drop chance %s). Since this is meant for a tool that will fill said configurations as a user wants, they can play with all values and the tool simply presents the effective drop chances (probability) for their current in-screen configuration. Yes, each item can have its own custom chance.

Comment: You're mixing code and words in ways that are hard to reconcile. What does picking Bset items have to do with the probability that item $x$ will be inside the box? Is Bset the number of items removed from the box? If so, how many items were in the box to begin with? Were all $n$ items in the box? If we always start with $n$ items in the box, why do you say that Bmax is the maximum number of items in the box?

Comment: It occurs to me that perhaps when you say "drop chance" you mean the chance of dropping an item _in_ the box. In my previous comment I thought you were dropping items _out_ of the box. It really is not clear from the description.

Comment: Just added an illustration to try and answer any pending doubts. Hope it helps passing my thoughts.